# dbms_transaction.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID returns null when calling through EJB

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic11g, ejb-2.x

I am trying to retrieve the local transaction id from a EJB via an oracle function. The function has the below statement

```
dbms_transaction.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID
```

However, when trying to execute the function through a EJB method the function returns null

`EJB2.0
Oracle Database
Weblogic`

Comment: Function returns null if there is not active transaction.

Comment: there is active transaction. thats where the issue is